# GeometryArray with COLOR_3 and lighting

Tags: 3d, java-3d

I'm implementing this in Java3D, but I think the question is related any implementation of 3D Graphics.

I am trying to make my Shape3D be affected by light. Let me explain what I am doing and what I have tried so far.

I have a few [`GeometryArray`](http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.4.0/javax/media/j3d/GeometryArray.html)s (in particular one `QuadArray` and two `TriangleArray`s) which I initialize using `COLOR_3 | COORDINATES` mask. Then I `setCoordinates` and `setColors` that I need. I also tried adding `| NORMALS` and calculating normals.

All `GeometryArrays` are geometries of a [`Shape3D`](http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.4.0/javax/media/j3d/Shape3D.html) object. The `Shape3D` object itself is child of a `BranchGroup` which is directly a child of universe.

I use following method to setup Appearance:

```
private void initAppearance() {
    Appearance app = new Appearance();
    Color3f objColor = new Color3f(0.3f, 0.2f, 0.1f);
    Color3f black = new Color3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    app.setMaterial(new Material(black, objColor, objColor, black, 100.0f));
    setAppearance(app);
}
```

I use following method to setup light:

```
private void makeLight(BranchGroup group) {
        Color3f lightColor = new Color3f(2f, 2f, 2f);

        Vector3f direction1 = new Vector3f(4.0f, -7.0f, -8.0f);
        Vector3f direction2 = new Vector3f(-4.0f, 7.0f, 10.0f);
        DirectionalLight light1 = new DirectionalLight(lightColor, direction1);
        DirectionalLight light2 = new DirectionalLight(lightColor, direction2);

        BoundingSphere bounds = new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 50.0);
        light1.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
        light2.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);

        group.addChild(light1);
        group.addChild(light2);
}
```

**This was working** when my `Shape3D` used `GeometryInfo` with `POLYGON_ARRAY` mask and with usage of methods `setCoordinates`, `setStripCounts`, `setContourCounts`. But I had to reimplement this using `GeometryArray`s, because I need to set different colors for each point.

*I know that initAppearance does almost nothing (at least nothing I can see), but I don't know how it should look like*

I hope I explained it well, but I can explain more and provide some more code if required.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem was that I was experimenting on only one of the geometries (while having three of them). I thought that when I use `| NORMALS` mask on only one of the Geometries, this one will use normals, but the other won't. But it occurs that when I set this mask on all of the geometries and set the normals it worked.